# Trying to read an Excel file with EPPlus works on the server, but not through a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, epplus

When I published my project and ran it **on** the server, it worked. EPPlus found all 4 worksheets, iterated through them, and uploaded my data to SQL.

But when I run it through my browser, or my coworkers browser, it shows 0 worksheets.

Any idea why this might be happening? There's not much to the code at that point, but here's that part:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(strFile)))
{
    if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count <= 0)
        strError = "Your Excel file does not contain any work sheets";
    else
    {
        foreach (ExcelWorksheet worksheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
```

Comment: So the working version was on the server but also from browser? The file was already on the server? The non-working version was via browser with an uploaded file? Have you checked if that file was uploaded correctly?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, it was through the browser on the server and the file was on the server. I'll double check to make sure the file was uploaded correctly, but if it wasn't, EPPlus usually throws an error.

Comment: `package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count` will never be less than 0. So you only need to test if it's equal to 0. I know that's not really related to what you're asking, but just an observation.

Comment: @mason Yup. It's just a habit.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just tried checking the package.File.Length property to see how large the file was after upload. But it threw an exception saying it couldn't find the file. I'm using a DevExpress control to upload the file. The file path it shows is "'C:\fakepath\." I guess EPPlus doesn't load the file into memory and instead needs a constant connection to the physical path.

Comment: @ernest: it seems that your problem is related to the file-upload and not to EPPlus. So you either have to edit your question to show the code where you upload the file or delete this question and ask another one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EPPlus can load a file into memory. You're just not doing it that way. I think if you do this, you're less likely to run into trouble reading it from the file system. You can turn uploaded files into a byte array without having it as a file first, but in my example I'm opening an existing file. If you provide the code for how you're uploading the file, I can update my example.

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\file.xlsx");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file))
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
{
    if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count == 0)
        strError = "Your Excel file does not contain any work sheets";
    else
    {
        foreach (ExcelWorksheet worksheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
```

Comment: @SatishKumarsonker Then you need to ask a new question and provide a [MCVE].