# Looping through sheets

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to use EPPlus to loop through an Excel workbook's sheets, but I'm not having any luck figuring out the syntax.

I'm using C# right now.  I was able to get it working in VB.NET, but not C#.

This is what I have that is *not* working in C#:

```
object Workbook01 = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(WorkbookFilePath).Workbook;

foreach (object sheet01 in Workbook01.Worksheets){

    // Code here.

}
```

This gives an error that says:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Worksheets' and no extension method 'Worksheets' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is what I have in VB.NET that works fine:

```
Dim Wkbk As Object
Wkbk = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(wkbkFilePath).Workbook

For Each sheet01 In Wkbk.Worksheets

    ' Code here

Next sheet01
```

Maybe it's a mistake to compare C# to VB.NET for this project, but, either way, I need to figure out how to loop through all sheets with EPPlus in C#.

Comment: What is the type of `ExcelPackage(WorkbookFilePath).Workbook`? Change `object` to that type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to read an Excel file with EPPlus works on the server, but not through a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717271/trying-to-read-an-excel-file-with-epplus-works-on-the-server-but-not-through-a)

Comment: @MethodMan not at all a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Workbook01` is an `object` here, so you only have access to the members of [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx):

```
object Workbook01 = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(WorkbookFilePath).Workbook;
```

If you don't want to write out the type name, use `var`:

```
var Workbook01 = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(WorkbookFilePath).Workbook;
```

You should do the same in your loop:

```
foreach (var sheet01 in Workbook01.Worksheets){
```

See [Difference between "var" and "object" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552881/difference-between-var-and-object-in-c-sharp) for an explanation on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

C# is a lot stricter with respect to types than VB.NET is (without Option Strict).

You need to declare a variable of type Workbook instead of object:

```
OpenOfficeXml.Workbook Workbook01 = new ...
```

VB.NET does some magic so that you can use the properties and methods of Workbook on an object variable. C# expects you to specify the correct type to avoid misunderstandings. You can also use the var keyword to let the compiler determine the right type of a variable.